# Error HTTP 503 when fetching a model from a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

I get a 503 HTTP error today when i try to fetch a model.

This code worked 2 days ago... I think the only difference is i updated node and its dependencies.

I get a `Origin MY_DOMAIN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` then, a 503 HTTP error on the GET request (with Chromium and Firefox).

The weird think is, i can curl the same url, the server handle it and return a response...

I made the server a simple as i could and it still doesn't works, here is the code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/user/:username/:facebook_id/:facebook_token', function(req, res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    console.log('Something is happening.. ');
    res.send({error: 'test'});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

And on the client side, i just call a fetch from a model...

```
initialize : function() {
    var that = this;
    this.model.fetch({
        success: function(_model){
            console.log('User fetched successfully on initialize');
            that.render();
        },
        error: function(_model, error){
            console.log('User fetched unsuccessfully on initialize');
        }
    });
```

I go to the error callback after the failed the GET request.

Does anyone has an idea ? Do you think it could be a conflict with the last update of express node and backbone ?

Thanks !

UPDATE:

Apparently it doesn't works because of my VPN, i am in China now... It could explain the not allowed errror. I'keep the subject update soon.

Comment: What is the response you are getting for `OPTIONS` request made by the browser? Are you setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for all the responses?

Comment: I just get a XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MY_DOMAIN:1000/user/anonymous/1235486421/AEZH93FZFEFSFSFS4545154sfsfSF. Origin http://MY_DOMAIN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. into my browser, i only get OPTIONS when i try to call a save(). And yes i gave you all my server code just among.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem came from my VPN which lock the URL to my own server since today, this is the reason about the "access is not allowed"...

Thanks for your help !